# DDD - Conditional business rules without a domain service

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Suppose you have a simple aggregate root like this:

```
Playlist {
  String name
  List<Song> songs

  add(Song song) {
    // Some business rules

    songs.add(song)
  }
}
```

Now suppose you want to introduce a business rule in the `add(Song)` method that depends on other aggregate roots. For example: A song may not appear in more than 3 playlists. One way to do this would be to fetch this information (number of playlists containing the song) in the application layer and pass it to the `add(Song)` method.

But now suppose furthermore that this business rule only applies under certain conditions. Imagine for example that playlists whose name starts with "M" don't have such limitation (completely arbitrary). Now fetching the information at the application layer would mean either implementing domain logic at the wrong level, or fetching data that you won't use. As business rules become more complicated this becomes more costly.

Now the obvious solution is: Use a domain service that has access to the Playlist repository and do your logic there. While this works, I was wondering if there is any pattern/architectural tip/reorganization that could be done to solve this problem without using a service to encapsulate the logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I know you said, "without a service", but I decided to just list all the various approaches I could think of to solve this problem (not all equivalent):

1. **AR (Aggregate Root) method receives pure external data**. Like you said, this is the simplest strategy, but falls a bit short for more complex scenarios. It also couples the AR to a specific kind of song playlist addition rule.
2. **AR method receives a strategy/rule**. The AR method is provided with a strategy (that could be impure) to enforce the rule. For instance, you could have a `SongPlaylistAdditionRule#check(Song, Playlist)` interface. The `Playlist` AR would just call on `rule.check(song, this)` to enforce it. The application layer would leverage some kind of rule provider to get the proper kind of rule or would be injected the right one through the IoC container.
3. **A domain service**. This one's pretty obvious, not going to explain.
4. **A synchronous policy (event handler) applies in the same transaction**. You'd have a `SongPlaylistAdditionPolicy` which listens to an event like `SongAddedToPlaylist` through an in-memory `DomainEventPublisher` allowing the policy to participate/execute in the same transaction. The `SongPlaylistAssociationPolicy` would live in the domain. It's similar to #2 & #3, but invoked indirectly.
5. **An eventual consistent policy**. Same concept as above, but would execute asynchronously in another transaction. You'd most likely permit the violation, but then inform the user later that the song was removed from the playlist because the policy got violated, or any other kind of compensating action.
6. **A saga/process manager**. You can think of this approach as the reservation pattern, where you introduce small strongly consistent transition states that moves towards a final goal. Each state transition is usually processed in it's own transaction and is rolled back through compensating actions in case of a failure. e.g.

   a) `playlist.add(song)` ⟶ fires `SongAddedToPlaylist`/throws: checks playlist-specific invariants (e.g. max number of songs in playlist)

   b) `song.apply(songAddedToPlaylist)` ⟶ fires `SongAdditionToPlaylistConfirmed`/`SongAdditionToPlaylistFailed`: checks song-specific invariants (e.g. how many playlists it belongs to)

It's important to note that of all the above, #1, #2, #3 and possibly #4 are all possibly stale checks, meaning they wouldn't necessarily prevent a rule violation through concurrency, unless you somehow lock all the data that's been read in the given transaction.

#5 could be used in combination of #1-#4 to reduce the number of accidental violations, but also cover scenarios where the rule got violated through concurrency.

#6 is probably the most natural one as from the domain's perspective it's pretty much all ARs. If you do not want to deal with eventual consistency you could always integrate in a way similar to #4 and have all ARs modified in a single TX. In that case you do not have to model the transition states either. Then when you need to scale you move to eventual consistency.

Hopefully this will give you some ideas on how to tackle your specific problem effectively! There's no one fits all solution!

Comment: Could you please talk more about the saga (#6) approaches?